# Is there any chart library working both on iphone and android applications?

Tags: iphone, android, charts

I need to develop an application on both iphone and android which have to support chart plots.
(Or perhaps a similar chart library for ios/android platforms.)

Or what do you recommend?
Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean a mobile website?  Not a native andriod/iphone app?

Comment: No, I meant a native android/iphone app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is a pure javascript charting library like [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/).

I've seen [plenty](http://rapidandroid.org/wiki/Graphing) of flot [tutorials](http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/2010/10/13/generating-graphs-in-android.html) for Android, and according to [this link](http://code.google.com/p/flot/issues/detail?id=273) flot works fine on iphone except for the mouseover events.

Answer (score 2):

If your app will work only online you can use this:

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

Comment: This doesn't work for me on android

Answer (score 2):

Please try this one for iOS: 
https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts

It is inspired by an Android library called MPAndroidChart.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking into building the application using Adobe AIR.