# Common Graphs library for Android and iphone

Tags: android, iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any chart library working both on iphone and android applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4995114/is-there-any-chart-library-working-both-on-iphone-and-android-applications)

I need to find a common library file to generate graphs for android and iphone. Please let me know if anyone know the library file.

Note: I need the library file to develop a native android/iphone app.

Comment: i think you need to use the share kit for the native application for social site connectivity

Comment: core plot for iPhone and Android plot for android are good tools

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these links. Hope any on following can be helpful.

[Steema](http://www.steema.com/)

[amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/)

[Android Plot(only for Android)](http://androidplot.com/)

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android/1856369#1856369) question